# Function not running after submitting name into prompt

Tags: javascript, function

entering correct student name associated with image within prompt but it is not running the "checkAnswer" function

this is the function

```
            function checkAnswer() {
            if (document.getElementById('response').value == personArray[currentId].firstname) {

            //NOTE TO STUDENT: apply the class to reduce the opacity of the image, 
            //takeout the mouse events because they shouldn't be there anymore
            document.getElementById(currentId).className = "opClass";
            document.getElementById(currentId).removeAttribute("onclick");
            document.getElementById(currentId).removeAttribute("onmouseover");


            //superimpose name on image
            var divVar = document.createElement('div');
            divVar.setAttribute('id', currentId + 'name');
            document.getElementById('pic-grid').appendChild(divVar);
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(personArray[currentId].firstname);
            divVar.appendChild(textNode);
            document.getElementById(currentId + 'name').style.position = "absolute";
            document.getElementById(currentId + 'name').style.top = y;
            document.getElementById(currentId + 'name').style.left = x;

            //clean up loose ends: hide the prompt, turn the frame white so it doesn't change to aqua on the rollover, erase the response and message
            document.getElementById('prompt').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(currentId).parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            document.getElementById('response').value = "";
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "";
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById('message').innerHTML == "Wrong!") {
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Incorrect answer!"
            } else {
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Wrong!"
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Basically if the user enters the correct name in the prompt that is associated with the image they selected, the image should fade (opacity) and display the name of the student in the image (style position, top, & left) or if they enter the wrong name they are told within the prompt that they are wrong or incorrect.
As soon as I enter the correct student name, the prompt disappears and nothing happens or if I do the wrong name, it disappears as well.

here is the populateImages function that i forgot to place in here, sorry.

```
        function populateImages() {

        for (var i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
            var imageContainer = document.createElement("div");
            var image = document.createElement("img");

            imageContainer.classList.add('frame');
            image.src = personArray[i].url;

            image.setAttribute('onclick','promptForName(this)');

            image.setAttribute('onmouseover','styleIt(this)');

            image.setAttribute('onmouseout','unStyleIt(this)');

            imageContainer.appendChild(image);
            document.getElementById('pic-grid').appendChild(imageContainer);

        }
    }
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<body onload="populateImages()">

<header>
    <h2>Class Flashcards</h2>
    <h3>Click on a student to guess their name</h3>
    <h4>Concepts: Rollovers, Opacity, Showing and Hiding Elements, Arrays of Objects, Adding and Removing Elements/Attributes Dynamically to the DOM,
        Accessing Elements using parentnode</h4>
</header>

<div id="pic-grid">
</div>

<div id="prompt">
    What is this student's name?<br>
    <form onsubmit="return checkAnswer()">
        <input type="text" id="response" name="quizInput">
    </form>
    <div id="message"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

the form is being submitted through this function and shows up when image is selected:

```
        function promptForName(element) {
        document.getElementById('response').value = "";
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('prompt').style.display = 'block';
        currentId = element.id;
        x = element.offsetLeft;
        y = element.offsetTop;
        x = x + 20;
        y = y + 20;
        document.getElementById('prompt').style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById('prompt').style.top = y;
        document.getElementById('prompt').style.left = x;
        document.getElementById('response').focus();
    }
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: Where's the `populateImages` function that should run first?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that oddly I do not get any errors in the console at all. I just edited my post and the populateImages is now up above

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Comment: form or "prompt" shows when an image is selected/clicked on and runs the promptForName function which i added to the post above.

Comment: I tried replacing return false with return true and for some reason it removed the first 2 images and unfortunately still did not run the function after submitting the form/prompt. 
I can paste the link to the template I am supposed to be going off of but need to mention that the template is running the images from the html and my code I am tasked to run them dynamically through javascript.

link - https://lfernandez.org/web_1430/flashcards/template.html

if you go to it just click the first image and enter the name "Abarnave" and that will show you what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: so actually noticed an error is now showing in the console that flashes and goes away very quickly after submitting the student name in the prompt it is:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined" then shows these lines of code: 
if (document.getElementById('response').value == personArray[currentId].firstname) - from checkAnswer function 
and 
<form onsubmit="return checkAnswer()"> - from the HTML

Answer (score 0):

return false cancels submit action. you must insert a return true if everything is ok

try this function

```
function checkAnswer() {
        if (document.getElementById('response').value == personArray[currentId].firstname) {

        //NOTE TO STUDENT: apply the class to reduce the opacity of the image, 
        //takeout the mouse events because they shouldn't be there anymore
        document.getElementById(currentId).className = "opClass";
        document.getElementById(currentId).removeAttribute("onclick");
        document.getElementById(currentId).removeAttribute("onmouseover");


        //superimpose name on image
        var divVar = document.createElement('div');
        divVar.setAttribute('id', currentId + 'name');
        document.getElementById('pic-grid').appendChild(divVar);
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(personArray[currentId].firstname);
        divVar.appendChild(textNode);
        document.getElementById(currentId + 'name').style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById(currentId + 'name').style.top = y;
        document.getElementById(currentId + 'name').style.left = x;

        //clean up loose ends: hide the prompt, turn the frame white so it doesn't change to aqua on the rollover, erase the response and message
        document.getElementById('prompt').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(currentId).parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        document.getElementById('response').value = "";
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "";
        return true; // return true if everything is ok
    } else {
        if (document.getElementById('message').innerHTML == "Wrong!") {
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Incorrect answer!"
        } else {
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Wrong!"
        }
        return false; // return false if error
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the return true above the else statement as you have in your post. The prompt/form is disappearing as it should but not running the checkAnswer function to fade the image and display the correct student name.

Comment: so watching the console when I hit enter to submit the student name I saw an error popup but it goes away in a flash, currently trying to stop it in the debugger. will keep you posted but any other ideas are obviously welcomed.

Comment: got the error down that flashes in the console: it is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined" then shows these lines of code:

if (document.getElementById('response').value == personArray[currentId].firstname)   - from checkAnswer function

and

<form onsubmit="return checkAnswer()">  - from the HTML

Comment: post the personArray value here, removing sensitive data